# Determine the range of τxz values for which the maximum tangential stress is less than or equal to 60 MPa

Tags: mechanical-engineering, solid-mechanics

Consider the state of tension indicated in the Figure. Determine the range of τxz values for which the maximum tangential stress is less than or equal to 60 MPa.

[image]

I did σ(med)=(60+0)/2 = 30

To find the radius I did σ(max) = σ(I) = σ(med)+r <=> 100=30+r <=> r=70

But in the solution is
[image]

My question is: why is my radius wrong?

Comment: Do not self-vandalize your questions, here or on other Stack Exchange sites like electronics.SE. This was a well-received question that was upvoted, with a good answer. The people answering have put in time and effort to write an answer -- These edits that remove the question contents are disrespectful to their work.

Comment: The account needs to be blocked before the questions are restored. It all seems pretty childish.

Comment: While this behaviour is completely unacceptable, I Found it a bit humorous that OP immediately undid the edit after a user undid his original edit on making the post about 'deleted question'

Comment: @Buraian The *answer* saying the same thing is even stranger -- OP should seriously stop -- the question has been flagged for moderator intervention here and they have been notified on multiple sites about these edits (by mods and non-mod users alike)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, however one way to feel more confident on my reasoning, is to check whether my final value of $\tau_{xz}$ is the same with the solution. .

My understanding is the following :

$\sigma_{xx}$ and $\sigma_yy$ are principal stresses in the x-y plane. That means that $\sigma_1 \leftarrow \sigma_{yy}$, $\sigma_2 \leftarrow \sigma_{xx}$. The greatest tangential stress is going to be obtained by the $\sigma_{I}$ and $\sigma_{III}$.

In order to have $\tau_max=60[MPa]$, you'd need $\sigma_{I}-\sigma_{III}=120[MPa]$ Therefore, since, $\sigma_1=100[MPa]$, $\sigma_{III} \rightarrow -20[MPa]$.

Then on the x-z plane, you'd need to determine the $\tau_{xz}$, so that the lowest principal stress is -20[MPa]. Since, on that plane the $\sigma_{med} = 30[MPa]$, then the radius will be $\tau_{xz,max} = 50[MPa]$, which means that you need to have

$$50^2 \ge \tau_{xz}^2+ \left(\frac{\sigma_x - \sigma_z}{2}\right)^2$$
$$\tau_{xz}^2 \le 50^2  -\left(\frac{\sigma_x - \sigma_z}{2}\right)^2$$
$$\tau_{xz} \le \sqrt{50^2  -\left(\frac{60}{2}\right)^2}$$
$$\tau_{xz} \le \sqrt{50^2  - 30^2}$$

$$\tau_{xz} \le 40 [MPa]$$

Is this the right solution you are given?